# bootstrap input box can not fill up the col, but just show up very short one

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrop to draw my page, The code is below.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    Test
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am curious why the input box can not fill all of the 'col-lg-6' but just a little short.

[Here is the fiddle portal.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnX8e.png)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your `col-lg-6` class is applied to the outer `<div>` rather than the inside one.

Try this:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-6">
    Test
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="input-group; col-lg-6">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Bootply results [here](https://www.bootply.com/UQuVtwmFYu).

Comment: Thanks Tim, I am still confuse that why I write it in the outer <div> can not get the result. The purpose of outer <div> here is to set the col-length.

Comment: @Jason.Chen Your original code sets up a div of col-lg-6 and inside this outer div, you created another div. The inner div only takes up a portion of outer div in case there are more than one inner div elements. Therefore, it does not occupy the full space.

Comment: I got it. Thanks a lot!